# SharePoint Online Remove link in web part title

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, delete

**How do I remove the link in a web part title? I want the title to be text only.**

- I am using SharePoint online and a PC with Windows 10.
- I do NOT have access to SP Designer
- The result is the same for Chrome and IE

I swear I used to be able to do this easily and now I can't.

1st idea - Modify Web Part Properties, clear the Title URL field value in the Appearance section, Click OK and it does NOT work. After reloading the page, SP automatically fills the Title URL property back in with the URL of the default view of the list.

2nd idea - Replace the Title URL value with a "#". In this case the link will not disappear yet it now links to the current page. Not what I want.

Comment: Are you using classic experience in sharepoint online site?

Comment: What web part are you dealing with? Would you like to provide a screenshot of your current page?